# Need feedback on finding natural log returns and linear regression slope with Python

Tags: python, scipy, linear-regression

I am trying to get the natural log returns of time series prices, and use them with the Python SciPy library (stats.linregress) in order to get the slope of the linear regression line. This is the first time I am trying this, and would very much appreciate another set of eyes and feedback. I think that there is a problem with the natural log returns part of the code.

```
symbols = ["'AAN'"]

# Getting x values (number of days in time series = 90)
xValues = []
x = 1
while x <= 90:
    xValues.append(x)
    x += 1

# print xValues

# The y values used in the stats.linregress method; 
# Currently I am getting them from a database, so I will 
# print out the returned values
yValues = []
for s in symbols:
    data90 = setup.last_90_closes(s)

for each in data90:
    # data90 returns a list of tuples, so I needed to 
    # extract the first element from each tuple
    i = each[0]
    yValues.append(i)

NewYValues = np.log(yValues)
# print NewYValues
# print yValues

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(xValues, NewYValues)


print slope
```

Results:
original yValues =

```
[31.93, 30.26, 29.86, 29.4, 29.37, 29.12, 29.51, 28.88, 29.01, 28.64, 28.63, 28.04, 27.97, 27.47, 26.75, 26.3, 25.71, 26.01, 25.26, 24.84, 24.81, 25.17,
24.71, 24.33, 22.63, 22.95, 23.1, 23.52, 23.23, 23.22, 23.56, 23.42, 22.82, 22.76, 22.77, 22.68, 22.81, 25.62, 25.13, 25.25, 25.17, 24.97, 24.95, 25.42,
24.69, 24.99, 25.14, 24.99, 25.66, 25.59, 25.09, 25.01, 25.01, 24.92, 25.01, 24.71, 24.99, 25.25, 24.73, 25.41, 24.92, 24.17, 24.78, 24.47, 24.36, 24.84,
 25.17, 24.71, 25.04, 25.27, 25.24, 25.23, 25.19, 25.18, 24.83, 24.9, 25.02, 24.76, 24.88, 24.53, 24.56, 24.55, 24.64, 23.94, 23.8, 23.68, 24.08, 23.93,
21.93, 22.88]
```

NewYValues =

```
[ 3.46354601  3.40982671  3.39651979  3.38099467  3.37997375  3.37142522
  3.38472919  3.36314931  3.3676406   3.35480434  3.35445512  3.33363206
  3.33113251  3.3130945   3.28653447  3.26956894  3.24688002  3.25848108
  3.22922212  3.21245526  3.2112468   3.22565281  3.20720802  3.19171016
  3.11927646  3.13331794  3.13983262  3.15785112  3.14544455  3.14501398
  3.15955036  3.15359036  3.12763734  3.12500461  3.12544388  3.12148348
  3.12719904  3.2433733   3.22406235  3.22882616  3.22565281  3.2176751
  3.21687382  3.23553627  3.2063983   3.21847574  3.2244602   3.21847574
  3.24493336  3.24220165  3.22246936  3.21927574  3.21927574  3.21567069
  3.21927574  3.20720802  3.21847574  3.22882616  3.20801708  3.2351428
  3.21567069  3.18511219  3.21003688  3.19744788  3.19294244  3.21245526
  3.22565281  3.20720802  3.22047455  3.22961792  3.22843004  3.22803376
  3.22644709  3.22605003  3.2120526   3.2148678   3.21967551  3.20922945
  3.21406427  3.19989686  3.2011191   3.20071185  3.20437114  3.1755507
  3.16968558  3.16463081  3.18138162  3.1751329   3.08785556  3.13026317]
```

slope =

```
-0.00157242772248
```

My question is: Do the results seem to represent what would be expected from the code?

Comment: You performed a regression and got the correct results given the variables you used. If the variables you used and how you used them are correct, well that is a different story.

Comment: If you didn't have expectations around the output, why even write the code?

Comment: @jonrsharpe When trying to learn a new concept, you have to start somewhere

Comment: But which is the new concept? You need some way to evaluate where you've got to, wherever you start, or you'll wander forever! This is why TDD can be useful, it forces you to think about what the code should actually *do* before you write it.

Comment: Got it! So, I was definitely expecting some sort of decimal (positive or negative) as the slope result. Based on the time series data inputs, it makes sense to be in the range of .0001 and .01 (not hard rules). I think what I was hoping for was somebody who is very familiar with the math behind this code, rather than the code itself. I should have clarified that.